# WM_PASTE hook not working

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I want to detect everytime I paste something. It's just something to make some data entry work simpler.
I set a global hook and then "wait" for the wm_paste. This is part of the code I have:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if(nCode < 0)//Do not process the message
        return CallNextHookEx(msg_hook,nCode,wParam,lParam);

    LPMSG m=(LPMSG)lParam;

    if(m->message == WM_PASTE)
    {
        OutputString("Paste detected!\n");
    }
    if(m->message == WM_PASTE)
    {
        OutputString("Paste detected!\n");
    }


    return CallNextHookEx(msg_hook,nCode,wParam,lParam);
    }





//DLL_ATTACH:
...
if(strstr(ProcName, LOADERNAME))
        {
            InitCommonControls();

            if(!(msg_hook=SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, GetMsgProc, hinstDLL, 0)))
            {
                ErrorExit(TEXT("SetWindowsHookEx"));
                //MessageBox(0, "WH_GETMESSAGE", 0, 0);
                //return -1;
            }
        }
```

WM_PASTE debug string never gets printed. I'm aware that not all applications use WM_PASTE. But at least notepad should work.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wm_paste message is fired only in combo box and edit control. There is no easy way to capture paste, but you can get copy message by creating a tiny window and adding this [window to the chain of clipboard viewers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

In [GetMsgProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644981%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the `wParam` parameter is not the message being intercepted, but a flag that indicates whether or not the message in `lParam` and been removed from the message queue.

You should be using `m->wParam` instead.

Comment: Indeed, while pasting the code here I pasted and old version of the code, and not the one with message.

Comment: Still, m->message or m->wParam doesn't work. Am I missing something here?